# PackageMaker command line option for requires restart

Tags: packagemaker

Im creating a build script to automate PackageMaker to install a kext, however I cant see the command line option for requires restart. Anyone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the following attribute in the Distribution file of your package.

```
<pkg-ref ...... onConclusion="RequireRestart"> ...... </pkg-ref>
```

More details about that attribute :onConclusion

Optional Attribute. Specifies the action to take after the installation
has finished. Values, from lowest to highest:

```
 None (default), RequireLogout, RequireRestart, or RequireShutdown.
```

The Installer takes the highest value from all enabled
packages and requires the associated action.